# Is there a way to easily test the speed and power capacity of a USB-C cable?

Tags: hardware, power, usb

Specifically in a macOS / iOS household (i.e. not looking for solutions that calls for Windows software).

I have a number from varying sources and definitely they are not equal. For example:

- The C-to-C cable that came with an Aukey power bank can deliver data but only at ~50Mbps however it can do 45W of power just fine.
- The C-to-C came with my Samsung T5 SSD can do 500+ Mbps but I'm not sure how well it can charge power banks.
- Apple's C-to-C cable bundled with recent MacBooks can do 87W (assuming from the capacity of the power brick that came with it), but I've read somewhere that it could only do USB 2.0 speed.
- A Baseus C-to-Lightning cable that charges an iPad Mini fairly quickly (using a MacBook charger), but never heard of "double beep" when plugging any iOS device indicating *fast charging enabled*.

Comment: According to Benson Leung's article ["How many kinds of USB-C™ to USB-C™ cables are there?"](https://people.kernel.org/bleung/how-many-kinds-of-usb-c-to-usb-c-cables-are-there), you're supposed to be able to tell the data speed from the logo. Note that it doesn't cover Thunderbolt 3 cables (and he's a Linux guy, so nothing about macOS). Power limit will depend on both the cable's current limit (cable-dependent, no idea how to detect) and the power source's current AND voltage limits.

Comment: The C-to-C cable that came with a Samsung T5 doesn't have any markings whatsoever.